# Drawing multiple particle elements on an html5 canvas without render kill

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

In the code below I am starting/stopping a flame of particles when clicking on a block. It works ok, however, I need to have about 10-20 flames able to start/stop individually and keep track of them. A friend suggested that I put each flame in a small canvas, then draw each canvas individually, which i think would be a rendering overkill, having 10-20 draw() running at the same time. How should i go about this?

One thing to note is that the position of the flame is given in particle(), then an array of particles is created, which basically represents the flame.

```
// init canvas
var canvas = $('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas[0].getContext('2d') // world
    ,
    ctx2 = canvas[1].getContext('2d') // fog
    ,
    context = canvas[2].getContext('2d') // flame
        ,
    mDown = false,
    r1 = 100,
    r2 = 300,
    density = .4,
    hideOnMove = true,
    hideFill = 'rgba( 0, 0, 0, 1 )'
    ,
    overlay = 'rgba( 0, 0, 0, 1 )',
    particles = [],
    particle_count = 100;
// init flame
for (var i = 0; i < particle_count; i++) {
    particles.push(new particle());
}

if (!hideOnMove) {
    // shouldn't be done like this, but this is a demo
    canvas.get(1).remove();
}

// black out the canvas
ctx.fillStyle = overlay;
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 1280, 800);

// set up our "eraser"
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';

canvas.last()
    .on('mousemove', function (ev, ev2) {
        ev2 && (ev = ev2);

        var pX = ev.pageX,
            pY = ev.pageY;

        // reveal wherever we drag
        var radGrd = ctx.createRadialGradient(pX, pY, r1, pX, pY, r2);
        radGrd.addColorStop(0, 'rgba( 0, 0, 0,  1 )');
        radGrd.addColorStop(density, 'rgba( 0, 0, 0, .1 )');
        radGrd.addColorStop(1, 'rgba( 0, 0, 0,  0 )');

        ctx.fillStyle = radGrd;
        ctx.fillRect(pX - r2, pY - r2, r2 * 2, r2 * 2);

        // partially hide the entire map and re-reval where we are now
        ctx2.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
        ctx2.clearRect(0, 0, 1280, 800);
        ctx2.fillStyle = hideFill;
        ctx2.fillRect(0, 0, 1280, 800);

        var radGrd = ctx.createRadialGradient(pX, pY, r1, pX, pY, r2);
        radGrd.addColorStop(0, 'rgba( 0, 0, 0,  1 )');
        radGrd.addColorStop(.8, 'rgba( 0, 0, 0, .1 )');
        radGrd.addColorStop(1, 'rgba( 0, 0, 0,  0 )');

        ctx2.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
        ctx2.fillStyle = radGrd;
        ctx2.fillRect(pX - r2, pY - r2, r2 * 2, r2 * 2);

    })
    .trigger('mousemove', {
        pageX: 150,
        pageY: 150
    });


function drawing() {
    // clear canvas
    context.clearRect(0, 0, 1280, 800);
    context.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";

    for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
        var p = particles[i];
        context.beginPath();
        //changing opacity according to the life.
        //opacity goes to 0 at the end of life of a particle
        p.opacity = Math.round(p.remaining_life / p.life * 100) / 100
            //a gradient instead of white fill
        var gradient = context.createRadialGradient(p.location.x, p.location.y, 0, p.location.x, p.location.y, p.radius);
        gradient.addColorStop(0, "rgba(" + p.r + ", " + p.g + ", " + p.b + ", " + p.opacity + ")");
        gradient.addColorStop(0.5, "rgba(" + p.r + ", " + p.g + ", " + p.b + ", " + p.opacity + ")");
        gradient.addColorStop(1, "rgba(" + p.r + ", " + p.g + ", " + p.b + ", 0)");
        context.fillStyle = gradient;
        context.arc(p.location.x, p.location.y, p.radius, Math.PI * 2, false);
        context.fill();

        //lets move the particles
        p.remaining_life--;
        p.radius--;
        p.location.x += p.speed.x;
        p.location.y += p.speed.y;

        //regenerate particles
        if (p.remaining_life < 0 || p.radius < 0) {
            //a brand new particle replacing the dead one
            particles[i] = new particle();
        }
    }
}

// set flame on/off
var myVar = 0;
var on = 0;
$('.c').css({
    left: "610px",
    top: "500px"
});
$('.c').click(function () {
    if (on == 0) {
        myVar = setInterval(drawing, 33);
        on = 1;
    } else {
        clearInterval(myVar);
        context.clearRect(0, 0, 1280, 800);
        on = 0;
    }
});

function particle() {
    //speed, life, location, life, colors
    //speed.x range = -2.5 to 2.5 
    //speed.y range = -15 to -5 to make it move upwards
    //lets change the Y speed to make it look like a flame
    this.speed = {
        x: -2.5 + Math.random() * 5,
        y: -15 + Math.random() * 10
    };
    //flame location
    this.location = {
        x: 640,
        y: 520
    };
    //radius range = 10-30
    this.radius = 10 + Math.random() * 20;
    //life range = 20-30
    this.life = 20 + Math.random() * 10;
    this.remaining_life = this.life;
    //colors
    this.r = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
    this.g = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
    this.b = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
}
```

See the full webpage here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hxrat

Comment: Haha, I recognize the fog of war codepen you borrowed some pieces of code from.

Comment: yeah, it was an awesome example :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some outside support and ended up doing it like this, which I think it's the best way to keep performance:

Create a small dummy canvas in memory to run the draw() of the flame

```
var flameCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
flameCanvas.width = 100;
flameCanvas.height = 400;
var context = flameCanvas.getContext('2d');
```

Use the big canvas to display copies of the dummy canvas wherever needed.

```
ctx3.drawImage(flameCanvas, 420, -37, 50, 200);
ctx3.drawImage(flameCanvas, 325, -47, 60, 240);
...
```

The rendering runs in the dummy canvas and the image is just copied all over, which increases performance so much. The only drawback is that all the flames will be the same.

To keep track of them, I surrounded each with an if clause

```
if (centerFlame_on) {
        ctx3.drawImage(flameCanvas, 590, 165);
    }
```

And I update centerFlame_on to true/false based on the mouse click.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably increase performance if you pre-generate the particles in a bunch of small canvases. Basically generate a list of particle-images with different colors and sizes and then use those for all the particles. Opacity can still be applied when the particle image is drawn. It should be faster to just draw a small canvas at a given position with a given opacity than to draw a path with radial gradient.

Here's an example, seems to double the performance at least: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Izqwu

I don't pre-generate particle canvases. Instead I wrote a function `getParticleCanvas()` which takes a color and returns a 32*32 pixel canvas (creates it once if it doesn't exist), which is then used in drawing(). The particale canvas is then drawn at the correct size and opacity. The position is rounded to the nearest pixel for performance.

Also, to reduce the number of possible particle canvases, the random colors are rounded to 8 different steps per channel:

```
this.r = Math.round(Math.random() * 8)*32;
this.g = Math.round(Math.random() * 8)*32;
this.b = Math.round(Math.random() * 8)*32;
```

You can probably decrease the radius in getParticleCanvas() from 16 to 8 without being noticeable as well.